# How to drop all tables that contain a certain string?

Tags: teradata

I need to drop tables that start with "my_database.test_table5 . . . "

how can I do this?

```
DROP TABLE * 
WHERE tablename IN 
(
SEL tablename 
FROM dbc.tables 
WHERE tablename like '%test_table5%' 
AND databasename = 'my_database' 
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to write and execute some dynamic SQL to pull that off since you can't dynamically replace objects in a SQL statement like you can values of a field. Although it's easy to get the two mixed up.

In your case, a very barebones stored procedure to do what you are wanting would look like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE your_db.drop_tables(IN tableName VARCHAR(30), IN dbName VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN

    --Variable for storing the matching table name inside the cursor loop
    DECLARE matchingTable VARCHAR(30);

    --Variable for storing the dynamic sql we will execute
    DECLARE strSQL VARCHAR(500);

    --Build the cursor for matching table names in the database.
    DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT tablename 
        FROM dbc.tables 
        WHERE tablename LIKE '%' || :tableName || '%' 
            AND databasename = :dbName;

    --Open the cursor and loop through results
    OPEN table_cursor;
    label_cursor_loop:
    LOOP

        --Catch any errors and get out if there is trouble.
        FETCH table_cursor INTO matchingTable;
        IF (SQLSTATE = '02000') THEN
          LEAVE label_cursor_loop;
        END IF;

        --Set up the drop table statement
        SET strSQL = 'DROP TABLE "' || dbName || '"."' || tableName || '";';

        --Execute the drop table statement
        CALL DBC.SysExecSQL( sqlStatement );

    END LOOP label_cursor_loop;
    CLOSE table_cursor; 

END;
```

You would then just call it and pass your database and search term for table names like:

```
CALL your_db.drop_tables('test_table5', 'my_database')
```

You could also choose to hard code that search term and the database into the SQL statement, but this is more fun this way, right?

Lastly, this will just indiscriminately drop any table that matches your search term, so proceed with caution. Keep the security tight and only use when you need the nuke option. Also, I only lightly tested this without executing the DROP TABLE sql.. so caveat emptor and all that.

Comment: Better switch to `dbc.TablesV` to get the long names and then you don't need the 2nd `'%'` in your WHERE-condition: `WHERE tablename LIKE '%' || :tableName` (because it's a `VARCHAR(128)` vs. `CHAR(30)`)

Comment: I'd suggest to change `WHERE tablename LIKE '%' || :tableName || '%' ` with `WHERE tablename LIKE :tableName` so the user can decide where to put the wildcard. In the user example (_I need to drop tables that start with "my_database.test_table5"_), the procedure could delete also the table `my_database.this_is_not_test_table5`.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a one shot task and you simply don't want to delete 20 tables by hand,  let the database write your SQL for you.

```
 Select 'drop table' ¦¦ databasename ¦¦ '.'  ¦¦ tablename ¦¦ ';' 
   From Dbc.TablesV
  Where databasename = 'mydatabase' 
    And tablename like 'test_table5%' ;
```

Then copy the result of this query and execute it.

You will find out that this 'let the database write your SQL' pattern will ease your tasks a lot.

If however this is a repeated task,  or to be done in a batch, go without any doubt for the procedure solution.

Answer (score 2):

Based on previous answers and comments, plus some fixes to actually make it work just thought I'd post a working proc:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE <your_db>.drop_tables(IN tableName VARCHAR(128), IN dbName VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN

--Variable for storing the matching table name inside the cursor loop
DECLARE matchingTable VARCHAR(128);

--Variable for storing the dynamic sql we will execute
DECLARE strSQL VARCHAR(5000);

--Build the cursor for matching table names in the database.
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT tablename 
    FROM dbc.TablesV 
    WHERE tablename LIKE :tableName
        AND databasename = :dbName;

--Open the cursor and loop through results
OPEN table_cursor;
label_cursor_loop:
LOOP

    --Catch any errors and get out if there is trouble.
    FETCH table_cursor INTO matchingTable;
    IF (SQLSTATE = '02000') THEN
      LEAVE label_cursor_loop;
    END IF;

    --Set up the drop table statement
    SET strSQL = 'DROP TABLE "' || dbName || '"."' || matchingTable || '";';

    --Execute the drop table statement
    CALL DBC.SysExecSQL( strSQL );

END LOOP label_cursor_loop;
CLOSE table_cursor; 
END;
```